# SQL query get row count in sorted table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SET @playerRank = 0;

SELECT *, @playerRank := @playerRank + 1 AS Rank FROM

( SELECT
  P.name AS nome,
  (playerMMR_RT(P.pid) - DecayTimeDiffRT(P.pid)) AS MMR,
  P.pid

FROM
players_rt P

 ) AS TableData

ORDER BY
MMR DESC,
nome ASC
```

Please note that `playerMMR_RT` and `DecayTimeDiffRT` return two integer values but that's not relevant. The result is this:

[image]

But I want this output:

[image]

---

Basically the result is good because the rows are sorted by `MMR`. I'd like the rank to be like 1, 2, 3... but it seems that it is sorted with the rows as well.

How can I fix this? I need the table to be sorted and the rank to go 1, 2, 3... in the sorted table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move the order  by inside the subquery

```
SET @playerRank = 0;

SELECT *, @playerRank := @playerRank + 1 AS Rank 
FROM ( 
  SELECT
  P.name AS nome,
  (playerMMR_RT(P.pid) - DecayTimeDiffRT(P.pid)) AS MMR,
  P.pid
FROM players_rt P
ORDER BY MMR DESC, nome ASC
 ) AS TableData
ORDER BY rank
```

Or try appply the rank at the ordered  result

```
SET @playerRank = 0;

SELECT t.*, @playerRank := @playerRank + 1 AS Rank 
from  ( 
  select *
  FROM ( 
    SELECT
    P.name AS nome,
    (playerMMR_RT(P.pid) - DecayTimeDiffRT(P.pid)) AS MMR,
    P.pid
  FROM players_rt P
   ) AS TableData
  ORDER BY MMR DESC, nome ASC
) t 
 order by rank
```

Comment: It does not work sadly. MMR uses 2 functions that use variables as well, may this be a problem? Of course all variables have different names